# How can I create an Accordion List within ionic 2?

Tags: toggle, accordion, ionic2

I want to integrate an accordion in my project using expandable groups but for a recent project, I was needing a rendition of an accordion that expanded text or more precisely overflowed content.

[image: accordion.jpg]

**Can you tell me how it will done within `ionic 2` ?**

Comment: Can you please share with us what have you tried so far?

Comment: i want to create an accordion list like this [screenshot](https://s31.postimg.org/jzd2yzp7f/accordion.jpg)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Check the demo of **accordion list** within `ionic 2` on **Github** :

https://github.com/mahmoudissmail/ionic2Accordion

*.html*

```
<ion-content padding>
  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Ionic 2 Accordion Example.
    </ion-list-header>
    <ion-item padding *ngFor="let d of data" (click)="toggleDetails(d)"><ion-icon color="primary" item-right [name]="d.icon"></ion-icon>
      {{d.title}}
      <div *ngIf="d.showDetails">{{d.details}}</div>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

*.ts*

```
export class HomePage {

  data: Array<{title: string, details: string, icon: string, showDetails: boolean}> = [];

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++ ){
      this.data.push({
          title: 'Title '+i,
          details: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.',
          icon: 'ios-add-circle-outline',
          showDetails: false
        });
    }
  }

  toggleDetails(data) {
    if (data.showDetails) {
        data.showDetails = false;
        data.icon = 'ios-add-circle-outline';
    } else {
        data.showDetails = true;
        data.icon = 'ios-remove-circle-outline';
    }
  }
```

thanks for @LPeteR90.

Comment: Great that really works...

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT:**

Ok, I think I've figured it out. [This tutorial](https://www.learnhowtoprogram.com/javascript/angular-js/adding-child-components-and-custom-event-emitters) helped me a lot, so I would recommend reading it also.

I've split my code up into components, where

```
@Component({
    directives: [DataCards], 
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/data-list/data-list.html'
})

export class DataList {

    public dataList: Data[];

    constructor() {
        this.dataList = [
            new Data('Test title', 'Test Details 1, 2, 3, 4, 5', false), 
            new Data('Second title', 'These are the details for my second title :)', false)
    ];
}
```

}

and the corresponding HTML

```
<ion-content class="cards-bg">
   <data-cards [data]="dataList"></data-cards>
</ion-content>
```

contain my custom component `data-cards`. `data-cards` has an input parameter `data`, through which the list of data is passed. To be able to use the `data-cards` component, you need to set the `directives` attribute. `Data` is a class containing everything you need in an item of your list.

```
export class Data {
    constructor(public title: string, public details: string, public showDetails: boolean) {}
}
```

The component `data-cards` itself has the selector and inputs attributes set, so the component can be used from the `data-list` HTML. The function `toggleDetails` is used to toggle whether the detail part of a list entry is shown.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'data-cards',
    inputs: ['data'],
    templateUrl: 'build/pages/data-cards/data-cards.html'
})

export class DataCards {
    public data: Data[];
    constructor() {}

    toggleDetails(data: Data) {
        if (data.showDetails) {
            data.showDetails = false;
        } else {
            data.showDetails = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, in the `data-cards` template file, I build up the list of data using `*ngFor` and make the details `<div>` element's visibility dependent on the data `showDetails` attribute with `*ngIf`.

```
<ion-card *ngFor="let d of data">
    <h1>{{d.title}}</h1>
    <button (click)="toggleDetails(d)">+</button>
    <div *ngIf="d.showDetails">{{d.details}}</div>
</ion-card>
```

To get everything to work you will need to add some imports to my code, since e.g. the `DataList` class depends on `DataCards` and `Data`.

I also recommend changing the style of the `data-cards` template... Without being styled, it doesn't look beautiful exactly :)

**UNEDITED ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I'm working on something similar right now. I think this can be implemented by using cards and `*ngIf`.

So I think I will do something like

```
<ion-card>
    <h2>Card Title</h2>
    <button (click)="toggleDetails()">+</button>
    <div *ngIf="showDetails">
        Here are some details for the title. 
    </div>
</ion-card>
```

In the `toggleDetails()` i would set the `showDetails` variable to true...

This is just my approach (and untested), I'm going to edit my answer when I'm done implementing it.

Comment: I'v updated the answer, since I've finished my implementation by now.

Comment: I'll try and tell us the result , thank you again :);

Comment: Please can you give me a **simple demo**  for that code ?

Comment: Tutorial is not available